# How to solve error Detected unknown BSON type

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

Hello I'm trying to figure out correct dependencies between org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync and org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb while using Mongo 4.4.6 database. Still getting:

```
2021-11-15 17:13:18,112 pool-9-thread-1 ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender console org.bson.BsonSerializationException: Detected unknown BSON type "\x73" for fieldname "tBatch". Are you using the latest driver version?
    at org.bson.BsonBinaryReader.readBsonType(BsonBinaryReader.java:95)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:82)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ByteBufBsonDocument.toBsonDocument(ByteBufBsonDocument.java:158)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AbstractByteBufBsonDocument.entrySet(AbstractByteBufBsonDocument.java:100)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ParameterFormatter.appendMap(ParameterFormatter.java:562)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ParameterFormatter.appendPotentiallyRecursiveValue(ParameterFormatter.java:498)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ParameterFormatter.recursiveDeepToString(ParameterFormatter.java:456)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ParameterFormatter.formatMessage2(ParameterFormatter.java:189)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ParameterizedMessage.formatTo(ParameterizedMessage.java:228)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.MessagePatternConverter.format(MessagePatternConverter.java:123)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.PatternFormatter.format(PatternFormatter.java:38)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$PatternSerializer.toSerializable(PatternLayout.java:345)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.toText(PatternLayout.java:244)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.encode(PatternLayout.java:229)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.encode(PatternLayout.java:59)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.directEncodeEvent(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:197)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.tryAppend(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:190)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.append(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:181)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:543)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:485)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:460)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:82)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.log(Logger.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2198)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2152)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2135)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2058)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1939)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.debug(AbstractLogger.java:480)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.sendCommandSucceededEvent(ProtocolHelper.java:289)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.LoggingCommandEventSender.sendSucceededEvent(LoggingCommandEventSender.java:142)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:306)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:258)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendAndReceive(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:99)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendAndReceive(DefaultConnectionPool.java:500)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl.execute(CommandProtocolImpl.java:71)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:224)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:202)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:118)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:110)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:343)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:334)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeCommandWithConnection(CommandOperationHelper.java:220)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:631)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:625)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withReadConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:462)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:625)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:77)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:190)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.execute(MongoIterableImpl.java:135)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.iterator(MongoIterableImpl.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2771)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2507)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2489)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:856)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:842)
```

Strange thing is that query is successfully executed, then response is passed to `CommandListener` and there, during logging it throws exception.

Could someone point me in right direction?

Comment: There is no type \x73 in [BSON](https://bsonspec.org/spec.html).  Are you able to run that query directly from a mongo shell?

Comment: Yes, as I said the query is successfully executed, then passed to CommandListener

Comment: Of course it was, and if you run the query in a mongo shell, you'll get to actually see that there is no field named `tBatch`.

Comment: yeah because broken driver, cuts "firstBatch" to "tBatch" while reading ByteBufBsonDocument

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by using `BsonDocument.clone()` in `commandStarted` in `CommandListener` implementation. The problem was that during executing command, buffer position is modified, so we cannot rely on it later within `commandSucceeded`